# Octal to octal multiplying in Java

Tags: java, performance

Can someone help me about multiplying octal to octal numbers in Java? I'm thinking if the user will input long octal number to be multiplied with another long octal number how would I do the result? Please show some codes. Thanks.

```
result = carry + result;
carry = result / 10;
numTemp = result % 10;
result = result - numTemp;
for(int ii = 0; ii < numArray.length; ii++){
  numArray[ii] = numArray[ii] / 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You multiply **[numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number)**, not **[string representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system)** of numbers, [**octal notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) is just one way of representing a number.

Just [**parse**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) the input into int variables, perform the multiplication and then print it out again. (Here: formatted in octal representation, but you can print the number in any format you want)

```
String num1 = "01234";
String num2 = "04321";
int result = Integer.parseInt(num1, 8) * Integer.parseInt(num2, 8);
System.out.printf("%#o", result);
```